# Black Screen - System will not resume after suspend on Lenovo T61 Thinkpad

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, 21.10

I am new to using Linux and have an old Lenovo T61 Thinkpad with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.10.

System Info:

- Memory: 3.8GB
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T7800@2, 6GHzx2
- Graphics: Llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 128bits)
- OS Name: Ubuntu 21.10
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Gnome Version: 40.4.0
- Windowing System: X11
- VGA Compatible Controller:NVIDIA CORPORATION G86M [QuadroNVS140M](rev a1)

All is well and suspend works perfectly using Win 10.

When I'm using Ubuntu the system goes into suspend but goes to black screen on wake up. I have tried many key combinations I have read about, none of which work. I can only use the power button (held down) to always reboot.

Is there a fix or workaround for this problem?

Comment: post please the output of the command `free` in terminal

Comment: A strange amount of memory, is that the installed amount or the output from some command?

Comment: Thanks Andra here are my comments using "free": Readout of “free” From Lenovo Thinkpad T61 using terminal.

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         3953364     1002496     1733756       12456     1217112     2694876
Swap:        2097148           0     2097148

Comment: David, This is the amount reported using "about".